# Want to indefinitely Observe an Array that changes over time

Tags: sockets, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use Rxjs Observables To watch for changes in my array with no luck.

Imports:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

In my main service in Angular 2

I am getting an array from a socket.io server that changes when users connect or disconnect.
I set the data after every change.

I know userList is Updating when the socket emits, but for some reason I can't figure out how to continuously observe this change in my component.

Main Service:

```
socket.on('get users',(data)=>{
        this.userList= data;
      });
```

Function in Main Service -  getUsers():

```
  getUsers(){
        return Observable.of(this.userList);
      }
```

I am trying to both subscribe to the userList var, and use an async pipe, but neither are updating, They only work the first time then stop.
How do I make it actually indefinitely observe for changes?

Answer (score 2):

**MainService**

```
userList: Subject = new Subject<any>();
userList$ = this.userList.asObservable();

socket.on('get users', (data: any) => {
   this.userList.next(data);
});
```

**In Component**

```
this.mainService.userList$
.subscribe( 
   (data:any) => console.log(data)
);
```

Comment: This works, except im running into one problem. Is there a reason why it doesn't initially pick up the first pack of Data in my component?

Comment: Currently It updates only when a new user comes in, but doesn't get the first stream of data.

Comment: Yeah, im trying everything for some reason it will not subscribe, until another user comes in. Any idea how to get that first subscription?

Comment: AFAIK Subject only emits when next is called. [reactivex subject docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) - Try using BehaviourSubject [also look at the rxjs subject docs on github](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)